# Punjab with new relic?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, newrelic, punjab

Is It possible to add an agent to punjab xmpp server?

I've seen that there is a experimental support for twisted apps. [newrelic info](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/python/status-of-python-agent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is experimental support for Twisted it is just that... experimental. New Relic does not have available instrumentation for XMPP entry points at this time. In short, there is not much that could be done with a Punjab/XMPP application using New Relic for now.

Comment: I work for New Relic and wanted to update that this "experimental" Twisted instrumentation is no longer being offered. We do not currently support Twisted, but feel free to reach out to us if you want us to file a feature request for consideration in a future release.